# How to sync from database in real time on Android without using huge performance

Tags: android, backend

So I am working with a quiz game in android where you are supposed to be two players playing against each other on different devices.

I am trying to figure out how the correct way is to set up the server communication to the devices. I want both devices to know when both players has given their answers to a question so they can receive the game result.

My first thought was that both devices will repeatedly ask the server if the other device is finished so they can have the game result. But I start thinking this is a bad idea as it will cause a lot of unnecessary traffic and probably some background performance.

So what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Android way of doing this would be using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM.) This approach is battery & processor efficient, supports broadcasting up to 1000 users at once and has built in functionality for outdated/expired messages.

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

Of course there are other ways of communicating that may be correct/right/valid but this approach is the best for your specified requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I've haven't worked with GCM yet but it looks like it will suit my needs.